# To find the angle of slipping of a falling coin

Tags: classical-mechanics, gravity, energy-conservation, rotational-kinematics

In an attempt to predict the outcome of a toss, I dropped a coin with its edge just touching another sharp edge as shown in figure. (The edge is flat and sharp with very less friction as in case of a blade)
[image]
I expected the calculations to be simple but it doesn't seem so.
The main issue is in finding the angle at which it slips and start falling freely.
Had gravity been a bit weak, I could have experimented but now I think I have to theorise it.

I would like to know the angle at which the coin would fall. If that is a wrong question to ask, then please explain how to find the angular velocity of coin during free fall.

Comment: Well if it is just touching the blade, I presume that the coin lifts of immediately. If the coin would be a certain distance $\epsilon$ on the edge, then the coin should leaf the edge when the angle of the coin is such that there is no more contact. $\cos \theta = 1- \frac{\epsilon}{d}$. This however neglects horizontal motions of the coin due to the edge. Is your question how this would affect the outcome?

Comment: @tomtom1-4 : yes it is. I would like to know the maths behind the spinning of the coin. Its angular velocity during fall.